# Varios paneles con fondo transparente en un formulario

Tags: c#, imagen

Estoy haciendo un *layout* de configuración de una sala de un restaurante, con sus mesitas, taburetes, barra, etc. Lo tengo ya prácticamente terminado, pero me surge un problema de diseño que no consigo solucionar. Verán, yo puedo agregar objetos a la sala (estos objetos tienen fondo transparente) y se insertan, y se mueven bien, se ve, digamos, **el suelo** detrás, sin problemas.

[image: Imagen 1 - objetos en la sala]

El problema viene cuando quiero colocar o mover alguno de esos objetos **encima** de otro ya existente. En la siguiente imagen se puede ver lo que trato de explicar.

[image: superposición de objetos]

La aplicación está hecha en *C#* y en el código del formulario están los eventos que hacen que los objetos, se coloquen y se muevan, nada del otro mundo. Los objetos realmente son paneles cuya imagen de fondo es la del objeto, y lleva un *label* para el numerito que está encima. ¿Debo utilizar otro tipo de contenedor?

Comment: Hola Mario. Siempre es útil incluir un [mcve]. No tiene por qué ser tu código tal cual. Puede ser, y de hecho es mejor que sea, una versión minimalista solo para que se pueda reproducir lo que dices.

Comment: Es una aplicacion Winforms? Wpf? Si es winforms...me parece que la solución va a ser complicada

Comment: Es una aplicación winforms, el caso es que ya he visto otras aplicaciones winforms (compiladas claro está) que lo hacen sin problemas, así, que posible tiene que ser y no creo que sea excesivamente complicado. La forma de reproducirlo es esa, cojer un formulario y ponerle una imagen de fondo que permita un dragdrop, luego, añade varios paneles con una imagen de fondo y que tenga transparencia y añades los métodos dragover necesarios para poder moverlos, verás que, efectivamente, la transparencia respeta el FONDO del formulario, pero si colocas un objeto encima de otro, pasa lo que veis ahí

Answer (score 1):

Los controles WinForms no manejan nativamente transparencias de una forma correcta. Supongo que en tus paneles lo que haces es utilizar un color transparente en tu panel, que utiliza un "truco" que basicamente consiste en hacer que el fondo lo dibuje el formulario padre (por eso ves que si que aparece el fondo, pero no el control que está debajo.

En principio yo pensaba que la solucion a esto no era sencilla, pero según la solucion expuesta [en esta pregunta en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463363/how-can-i-set-the-opacity-or-transparency-of-a-panel-in-winforms) al parecer, creando un control `Panel` personalizado parece que es posible. Te copio el código de ese control aqui:

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
    {            
        get {
            CreateParams cp =  base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
            }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) 
    {
        //base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pikoh, pero no me sale, o yo no se hacerlo, la cosa incluso ha empeorado, ahora los objetos se cortan o aparecen áreas borradas cuando muevo otros por encima y si lo dejo uno encima del otro sigue apareciendo igual. A lo mejor no he seguido bien el post, voy a seguir investigándolo, estoy seguro que los tiros debe ir por ahí, bichearé las referencias que hay en ese post. Gracias.

Comment: No lo he probado, pero echa un vistazo a la respuesta a [esta pregunta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32402532/579895). Tal vez te sirva.

Comment: Gracias a todo pero tampoco me sale, me parece increíble que una cosa tan básica como es mover objetos por un fondo sea tan enrevesada. Tengo programas antiquísimos en visual Fox Pro y eso lo hace perfectamente sin problema alguno. Bueno, sigo intentántolo, gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Comment: @MarioRodríguez De todas maneras, winforms es una tecnología anticuada. Para proximos proyectos, utiliza WPF que soluciona todos esos problemas.

Comment: Gracias Pikoh, pero en estos momentos no tengo yo teimpo de "aprender" un nuevo entorno, ya intenté cosas con WPF y me desespera que los objetos no estén donde yo los pongo y cambia muchas cosas a las que estoy acostumbrado, yo hago programas sencillos de gestión y WForms me resuelve al 100% mis necesidades, será tecnología obsoleta, pero eso llevan diciendo 15 años de Visual Basic y fíjate, se niega a desaparecer y hay programas de bastante éxito ya no echos en .net, si no en vb6 o incluso Visual Fox Pro, ahí es nada. Gracias por tu consejo.

Comment: Mario, ha pasado tiempo y me he inquietado en si has logrado solucionar tu problema. Te dejo un gif de algunas pruebas que he hecho: https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-aed6764391.gif